# Vercel cannot find static files from node_modules in NextJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, vercel

I have a simple NextJS API page which just fetches a JSON file from one of the `node_modules` and shows the content at `http://localhost:3000/api/my-json`. This is the code:

```
// Path: /pages/api/my-json.ts
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import path from "path";
import { promises as fs } from "fs";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  //Find the absolute path of the json directory
  const jsonLocation = path.join(
    process.cwd(),
    "node_modules/@my-company/my-package/lib/my-json-file.json"
  );
  //Read the json data file data.json
  const fileContents = await fs.readFile(jsonLocation, "utf8");
  //Return the content of the data file in json format
  res.status(200).json(fileContents);
}
```

It works fine in dev mode, also works when building a production NextJS app by running:

- `yarn install`
- `yarn build`
- `yarn start`

But when I upload the code to [Vercel](https://vercel.com/), the app is unable to find the json file, and my page `https://my-app.vercel.app/api/my-json` returns **500 error**:

```
2022-12-12T10:25:14.142Z    04b6a8fe-53f7-46b6-8c49-98dadf358eb3    ERROR   [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/node_modules/@my-company/my-package/lib/my-json-file.json'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/var/task/node_modules/@my-company/my-package/lib/my-json-file.json'
}
```

Somebody had this problem before? Do I need to copy that JSON file manually somehow during Vercel deployment? How comes it works on local builds but not on Vercel?

Comment: did you solve that problem? seems I am on the same boat now...

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/5182